# Linearization of Simulink nonlinear state space models with Linearize

Tags: matlab, simulink, integrator

States of the system in `Simulink Conttrol Design` are identified at the output of the integrator blocks accross the system.

If a model is already developed in a state space form, and specifically, integrators are already implemented in, for example, forward Euler form, how can one "inform" `linearize` command on what the states of the system are?

In simple words, how to use `linearize` for a high order dynamics system that does not contain any Matlab integrator block?

Comment: "*integrators are already implemented in, for example, forward Euler form*". In simulink or matlab? How? Can you provide a small example? Is it implemented with memory blocks? Please add more details, preferably a simplified example.

Comment: @AJN. Yes implemented with memory (delay) blocks in Simulink. It can be as simple as y[t] = x[t]*dt + x[t-1]

Comment: Then the state's can be identified as the memory blocks themselves. You have effectively converted a continuous time system with integrators to a discrete time system with memory blocks. I would not be surprised if matlab already knows that the states of the system include the memory blocks. I don't know about*linearize* command, but when calling simulink via `sim` command from matlab, matlab already knows that delay blocks contribute to states of the system just like integrators.

Comment: Just use the`linearise` command and see if the resulting system has the same number of states as the number of *unit-delays* in the simulink block diagram (assuming no state get deleted due to optimisation)

Comment: Thanks @AJN. I've tried that before and linearize spits our empty A/B/C matrices. It seems to be not as smart to identify the states that I've already developed. Besides, not all memory blocks are associated with the states as some might simply represent a (or multiple) sample time delays.

Comment: **1)** AFAIK, all memory blocks should correspond to a state of the *discrete-time* system.  **2)** Check the properties of the memory blocks in simulink. There may be some option to select what happens to this block during linearisation **3)** Are you using [unit-delay](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/unitdelay.html) or [something-else](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/memory.html) ? Both options behave differently while linearising, I think. [Read this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/linearizing-models.html).

Comment: The unit-delay block results in states being created. **4)** It would be best if you can post the screenshot of a minimum non-working block diagram including the "settings" dialog box of the delay block.